# Bat files as child process of each other

Tags: batch-file, cmd, subprocess, parent-child, child-process

Let's assume the following bat files :
**run.bat** :

```
start notepad.exe
start /min one.bat
start /min two.bat
```

**one.bat** :

```
program1.exe
```

**Two.bat** :

```
program2.exe
```

I want run **run.bat** and **one.bat** and **two.bat** so when I close **run.bat**, **one.bat** and **two.bat** get closed automatically. Also, I want all files to run independently from each other so I don't have to wait for **one.bat** to finish execution to run **two.bat**.

**edit 1** :
In other words, I need to run one.bat and two.bat as a child process of run.bat so when run.bat killed ( closed somehow ) one.bat and two.bat get killed too. It's like running it a subprocess.

Comment: Based upon what you've submitted, `run.bat` will already close as soon as it has executed the command `start /min two.bat`. I think therefore that we need more information about how you are running `run.bat` and what exactly you've tried yourself. Currently your question is lacking any problematic code, or an indication of any self effort.

Comment: Is it more clear now ? 

I dont want run.bat to close as soon as it finishes execution. run.bat is a program that will be running for a long time ( it's a back end server ). I just want the other programs to get closed as so as the main program ( run.bat ) got closed.

Comment: I'll ask again, how are you executing `run.bat`? What is currently happening when you run it? What have you researched and written in an attempt to achieve the intended goal. Currently your question in How do I perform a specific task? not how do I fix a specific issue with my programming code? This site deals with the latter. I would advise that you use the search facility at the top of the page, research, then write some code according to the results.

Comment: It's a bat script. that means it's gonna being executed by "double clicking it" . I have tried to search on the topics but did not find a question asked about running bat files as child processes of other bat files.

Comment: It doesn't mean that \`it's gonna being executed by "double clicking it"´, otherwise I wouldn't have asked. _(`one.bat` and `two.bat` clearly aren't being run by double clicking them, are they?)_. Also there are already several questions and answers about running parallel processes, and about the closure of processes based upon one or more triggers. I also asked you to tell us what happens when your current script, as posted above, is run. Please try harder.

Comment: However from what you are telling us, it appears that you'd need to run another background process or service, which would monitor the `cmd.exe` process which hosted `run.bat`, and trigger a termination of the two `cmd.exe`/.bat processes and/or the executables they themselves had invoked. This is far too much for a question on this site. You need to break that task into smaller parts and introduce each to the main script once you have those working as intended.

Comment: Let's clear some points: **1-** As written, the **run.bat** file _starts_ (in parallel) the `one.bat` and `two.bat` files and continue, so it ends immediately after that. You said: _"I dont want run.bat to close as soon as it finishes execution"_, but _all programs_ closes as soon as they finishes execution! What is the difference with `run.bat`? Please, write it complete.

Comment: **2-** As written, both `one.bat` and `two.bat` are NOT childs of `run.bat` because they run _in parallel_ with it. If `run.bat` run a process as a child, then `run.bat` MUST WAIT for the child to end in order to continue its own execution (this is the way all programs works in the computer). I suggest you to think in what you want and not request something that don't follow the operation rules of Windows! **`:/`**

Comment: @Aacini I think this is a miss undertraining here. I guess I miss understood the name "child process".

Comment: Ok lets make this super clear. **one.bat** is a back end server **two.bat** is another back end server. **run.bat** is a desktop application. I want to write a script to start all 3 : both back end servers and the desktop application in parallel but When I close the desktop application both back end server should be closed too. Because executing some commands in parallel ( each command would have it's own terminal) means each command would have it's own process. so these process are not related because they are paralyzed together.

Comment: My idea was to make a bat file for each server (**one.bat** and **two.bat** ) and make another bat file ( **run.bat** ) so the third bat file will connect all processes ( **one.bat** process and **two.bat** process and the desktop application process ). So when I close that main bat file ( **run.bat** ) all other processes should be closed too.

Comment: and the reason of make a bat file for the back-end server is : Once I started the back end server it will not finish execution. So If I tried to execute both back-end servers in the same terminal window, The second back-end server will never be launched. because the first server didn't returned yet. And I guess the concept of the server is to stay on and no returning at all unless you shut the server down.